# Automatically add a subclass to a list when it extends a superclass

Tags: java

Here is what I would like to do:

Say I created a class called Animal. Then I create a class called Dog that extends Animal. With only doing that, is it possible to add Dog to a list in a 3rd class called AnimalManager? It's fine if I have to call a method in the Animal class, but I want an instance of Dog to be created without hardcoding an instance of Dog. This seems like it might not be possible. Note: I only want one instance of each class.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Update:

This is a way better description of my problem. It also has a solution. I was able to find this with your guy's help. Thanks for the help! [At runtime, find all classes in a Java application that extend a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class)

Comment: I think you should consider using the *Java Service Provider Interface* for this, i.e. the `ServiceLoader` class. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), as well as articles at [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) and at [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi).

Comment: It is better if you could show us what you tried with some code snippets

Comment: I will try the recomendations you guys gave. If it doesn't work I will provide an exmaple.

Comment: It seems this question is obsolete as your update suggests you found the answer elsewhere. Please consider to remove the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("cz.milanhlinak.animal");
Set<Class<? extends Animal>> animals = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Animal.class);
```

See my example repository https://github.com/milanhlinak/62481200 where I use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) + [Google Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) for dependency injection.

Using Reflections you can get all sub types of your Animal class and add them to Google Guice Multibinder. After that, you can inject them somewhere...

```
// cz.milanhlinak.Module.java
public class Module extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("cz.milanhlinak.animal");
        Set<Class<? extends Animal>> animals = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Animal.class);

        Multibinder<Animal> animalBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Animal.class);
        animals.forEach(animal -> animalBinder.addBinding().to(animal));

        bind(AnimalProvider.class).to(AnimalProviderImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}

// cz.milanhlinak.animal.Animal.java
public abstract class Animal {

    private final String sound;

    public Animal(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    void makeSound() {
        System.out.println(this.sound);
    }
}

// cz.milanhlinak.animal.Dog.java
public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog() {
        super("Bark");
    }
}

// cz.milanhlinak.animal.Cat.java
public class Cat extends Animal {

    public Cat() {
        super("Meow");
    }
}

// cz.milanhlinak.animal.AnimalProvider.java
public interface AnimalProvider {

    Set<Animal> getAnimals();
}

// cz.milanhlinak.animal.AnimalProviderImpl.java
public class AnimalProviderImpl implements AnimalProvider {

    private final Set<Animal> animals;

    @Inject
    public AnimalProviderImpl(Set<Animal> animals) {
        this.animals = animals;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Animal> getAnimals() {
        return this.animals;
    }
}
```

You can also check [Google Guice - how to automatically add binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915611/google-guice-how-to-automatically-add-binding) where I was looking for something similar, but based on custom annotations.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add an instance extends Animal to the list in AnimalManager, right?

Make a public method in AnimalManager that get an Animal object as an argument, and add it into its list.

something like: "public void addToList(Animal obj)"

And call it in Animal's constructor. This makes whatever extends Animal would be added to AnimalList if you call super's constructor.